# Evaluating if the function returns truthy or falsey

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function which returns the greater number out of two given numbers, then I want to evaluate if given two numbers, the greater number is the correct output. However I keep getting false,

I have tried the following code or some small variations on it.

```
function maxNumber(n1, n2) {
    if (n1 > n2) {
        console.log(n1);}
       else {
            console.log(n2);
        }
    }

function testMaxNumber() {
    console.log(maxNumber (0, 10)===10);
};
testMaxNumber();
```

> 10 (this part is what I expected, the second log outputs
>   false//I expect true

Comment: Neither function returns anything

Comment: `console.log(maxNumber(0, 10))`

Comment: Neither function returns anything just as @j08691said, also I think you should be using `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: They dont `return` anything, but they print it in the console, so it "returns" the value in the console.

Comment: @PedroRoweder: Returns the value in the console? That doesn't compute.

Comment: `function maxNumber(n1, n2) { return n1 > n2 ? n1 : n2 }`

Comment: @ziggywiggy um.... no

Comment: And do you know that this exists? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 1):

In the `first function`, you need to `return` the value, so that it can be compared in the next one. So, your code would be something like this:

```
function maxNumber(n1, n2) {
    if (n1 > n2) {
        return n1;
    }else {
        return n2;
    }
}

function testMaxNumber() {
    console.log(maxNumber (0, 10)===10);
};
```

Notice that now the function is actually `returning` a value, not only printing it on the console.

Comment: thanks, I realize I was console logging and not returning the value, I am really really new to this. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help, if you marked this answer as correct, I would appreciate! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to return the number on each if block. Run the snippet below.

```js
function maxNumber(n1, n2) {
    if (n1 > n2) {
        console.log(n1); 
        return n1; //is is what is required
    }
    else {
        console.log(n2);
        return n2; //is is what is required
    }
}

function testMaxNumber() {
    console.log( maxNumber (0, 10) === 10 );
};

testMaxNumber();
```